How to trace cause of low performance between Azure VM and Azure Database for MySQL
I am running a Django application with a MySQL backend on Azure. The Django application is hosted on a VM in Azure while the database is hosted on Azure Database for MySQL. Both are in the same region, part of the same VNET. Accelerated networking is enabled on the VM.
When I compare the speed at which the initial database migrations run when running everything locally on my development machine (Macbook M1 Pro), it is orders of magnitude faster than when running in the Azure environment. I suspect this is because there is hugely improved bandwidth and disk IO when running everything locally on the Macbook.
The challenge I face is identifying how to change / rearchitect my Azure environment for optimal speed. I have tried increasing the compute on the Azure Database for MySQL to some of the fastest memory-optimised SKU's available, and I have tried provisioning increased IOPS to the service too. I wonder if there's potentially something I'm missing - perhaps the latency / connectivity between the VM and the MySQL instance?
I haven't found any information in Azure documentation about effectively profiling the speed / performance of the database. The main source of information I have used to date is the performance best practises docs that Azure publishes.
How can I form a strategy to profile the performance, and are there any obvious tips I can follow to ensure high performance read/write between Django and the Azure MySQL?

Look for the "worst" queries; see SlowLog  Then, let's discuss optimizing them.

Additional DB information request from your Azure MySQL instance, please.
OS, Version?
Azure instance type? RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server?
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links.
From your SSH login root, Text results of:
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Azure does not provide any way to update the connection "settings" from your end, you are able to use the MySQL, but at the end of the day, still a managed service, usually the way you handle the queries are better options to avoid bottle necks, or try to use a replica near your region, but if the issue persists after increasing DTU/IOPS maybe you should try to reach MS support.
